# What do the metrics used in a Broadband modem details page mean in layman's terms?

Tags: internet-connection, modem, adsl, upload, broadband

More like "Higher the better" or "Lower the better" Kind of way. I'm trying to Figure out why my connection has low upload speed.

```
+------------------+------------+----------+------+
|                  | Downstream | Upstream |      |
+------------------+------------+----------+------+
| SNR Margin       | 6.4        | 3.1      | db   |
+------------------+------------+----------+------+
| Line Attenuation | 24.8       | 19.6     | db   |
+------------------+------------+----------+------+
| Data Rate        | 4123       | 615      | kbps |
+------------------+------------+----------+------+
| Max Rate         | 6196       | 524      | kbps |
+------------------+------------+----------+------+
| CRC              | 28105      | 3027     |      |
+------------------+------------+----------+------+
```

Addition Modem Info:

```
╔═══════════════════════╦═══════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Modem Name            ║ iBall Baton 150m wireless-n adsl2+ router ║
╠═══════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ ISP                   ║ BSNL Broadband                            ║
╠═══════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ ADSL Firmware Version ║ FwVer:3.20.17.0_TC3087 HwVer:T14.F7_11.2  ║
╠═══════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Line State            ║ Showtime                                  ║
╠═══════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Modulation            ║ ADSL2 PLUS                                ║
╠═══════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Annex Mode            ║ ANNEX_M                                   ║
╚═══════════════════════╩═══════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Update:

*My friend fixed the cables today and speed is much better now. After changing the cable, what happened is, Upstream SNR margin Increased, Line attenuation reduced and CRC is almost Zero. So, I got my answer. Thanks for the help guys.*

Comment: "Figure out why my connection has low upload speed." - It is slow because you only were transferring at 524 kbps which is about 0.5 Mbps.  Now if you were connected over 802.11n you might get faster rates with 802.11ac but that would require different hardware.  Additionally if you were connected over an Ethernet connection it might be faster (I know nothing about your internet plan hence the "might").

Comment: @Ramhound nothing in that table implies anything to do with wireless; the upload rate there is between modem and isp (cabinet).

Answer (score 1):

Your "slow" upload speed is perfectly normal and is the reason why there is an "A" in ADSL.

The A stands for Asymmetric, meaning that upload and download speeds are going to to be different. You have fast download but slow upload. Typically the upload speed is of the order of 1/10th of the download speed.

If you want fast uploads then you want SDSL, or Symmetric Digital Subscriber Line, where upload speeds match the download speed but these can be quite expensive.

ADSL is cheap and suits *most* home users, SDSL is more expensive and until the recent boom in people casting their games and shows via services such as Twitch and YouTube was not seen as a priority.

Upload speeds on fibre and cable services have been improving, but most connections will still be "Asymmetric".

Answer (score 1):

"SNR" is [Signal to Noise ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio). **SNR Margin (db)** is the difference between the actual SNR and minimal SNR required to sync at a specific speed. Higher is better.

**Line Attenuation (db)** is a measure of signal degradation from your ISP(?) to you. Anything below ~30dB is fine. Lower is better.

**Data Rate (kbps), Max Rate (kbps)** is your bandwidth. Higher is better.

**CRC** is probably a straight count of [Cyclic Redundancy Check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) errors. It may be a rate (CRC fails per time) but not clear from the UI. Lower is better.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you @RJFalconer

Comment: When the SNR margin is low Modem restarts often. When I googled, I found this website [link](http://www.binarytides.com/fix-bsnl-broadband-frequent-disconnection-problem/). It says SNR MArgin Should be 20 dB to get a stable connection.

Comment: At least 20dB. Yes, I had it as "Lower is better" before. Corrected, ty. You want a *High* `SNR` and a *High* `SNR Margin`.